# Storing and dynamically loading pdf files from server in node js

Tags: android, node.js, android-studio, pdf, handlebars.js

I am trying to create an app that displays a list of pdf files, and then load the pdf file in a new browser tab / android activity.

The idea is the user will click a button "Lectures" and then will be shown the list of lectures, clicking on any list item will load the specific pdf file.

I currently have a node js mysql back end, for user login and routes to other pages, which is followed up with both a handlebars and android front end.

I am struggling to understand how I can store pdf files so they can be called based on what the user clicks, I want to store the pdf files on a server rather than within my application and then call them when required.

I have seen a method using ejs view engine to render list of files in public folder, which then allows you to do this, but this entails storing pdfs within the application, alternatively I can host the files with my web hosting, still need to figure out how to load them based on user action.

Would appreciate any direction or solution!

Thanks in advance

Mohamed V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing how you have the DB set I will talk more along the lines of how you would do this and then modify as needed. In most cases you would probably want to use an object store to store the PDF files. This will allow for access on any application.

1. Your DB should contain a file name of the PDF file, as an example, lets say you table for 'files' is as such

id, filename, name, extension, courceID

Here you would have the filename maybe the extension type and a refrenceID

2. Next, in your response callback, you simply return the query for the files, for example let say you run a query like SELECT filename, name WHERE courceID = '12345'

You then return this to the view, if its ejs then you would just pass the object and do something like

```
<% for ( in in files ) {%>
<div><a href="url-to-object-store/<%-files[i].filename%>"><%-files[i].filename%>
<%}%>
```

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response! so currently my db has 2 tables, 1 for the user details(name, email, password, study level), the 2nd table is currently all the module details(module code, module title, study level) for each level, so using your method I would create a 3rd table with pdf file names as you have shown.

Comment: Yah, typically you would do it this way, that way would would simply map it to the module detail via the module ID or multiple ID's if a PDF is used for more then one module.